# Become interested in what you're doing very much

Tags: meaning, word-request, phrase-request

I'm trying to express the following idea:

Imagine that I started working on a project and the project turned out to be so interesting that I spent almost all my free time to work on it. How can I express it in a way that is shorter?

> When I started working on the project I _____

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice poetic word for this is 'absorbed.' I would use it like so:

> When I started this project, I quickly became so absorbed in it that I lost track of all my free time.

Other good words that come to mind: obsessed (you couldn't think about anything else), intrigued (unexpectedly interested, especially for the purpose of gaining knowledge), devoted (caring about it more than anything else, emotional attachment).

Answer (score 2):

> When I started working on the project I ***became obsessed***.

CDO defines the word as:

> **[obsessed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/obsessed)** (*adj*.) unable to stop thinking about something : *The kids are obsessed with video games.*

While TFD says:

> **[obsess](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obsessed)** (*v.*) To preoccupy the mind of (someone) excessively

---

It's not uncommon to use this word when talking about projects; here are just a few examples:

> **From an [educator's blog](http://astrosociety.org/edu/publications/tnl/48/change2.html)**: *The students became obsessed with the project. Several of them told me that work in their other classes was suffering because they were so fascinated with this topic*.
>
> **From a [2015 news article](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/world/the-greatest-films-hollywood-never-finished/story-fnb64oi6-1227370308051) discussing unfinished cinema projects**: *He [Welles] too became obsessed with the project, talking about it until his death four decades later*.
>
> **On the [building of a canal](http://csfcanaldumidi.org/route-map/canal-du-midi/) in the 1600s**: *A brilliant civil servant by the name of Pierre-Paul Riquet had become obsessed with the project, and he believed he had the solution*.
>
> **From an [artist's chronicle of his work](http://www.artcreamtruck.com/#!Life%20In%20a%20Shed%20/zoom/c22qa/image8im)**: *Obsessed with the project I only cared about it's [sic] progress and my dog.*

Comment: Are you sure that obsessed is a good word to use in such a context? Why don't we just say something like `dive into work`... As far as I know it means the same.

Comment: I gave you two definitions along with four examples – I don't know what else you want. _Imagine that I started working on a project and the project turned out to be so interesting that I spent almost all my free time to work on it._ Yes, the word _obsessed_ can be used to describe that exact situation.